# Like feedback using firebase crash. Fast click like-remove like

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, user-experience

I have an application like instagram. It has feedback page.

When user likes some post, I add this like and feedback (with its own key (`.childByAutoId`) for this like.

```
static func add(_ newLike: LikeItem) {
  // add like id for user feedback implementation
  var like = newLike
  let likeRef = ref.child("/userslikes/" + newLike.userId + "/onposts/" + newLike.postId).childByAutoId()
  like.key = likeRef.key

  var updates: [String: Any?] = [
     "/userslikes/" + like.userId + "/onposts/" + like.postId: like.toAnyObject(),
     "/postslikes/" + like.postId + "/"         + like.userId: like.toAnyObject()
  ]

  if like.userId != like.postAddedByUserId { // dont add your own likes
     var likeForFeedBack = like.toAnyObject()
     likeForFeedBack["isViewed"] = false // when user will open feedback -> true
     updates.updateValue(likeForFeedBack, forKey: "/feedback/" + like.postAddedByUserId + "/" + like.key)
  }

  ref.updateChildValues(updates)
}
```

It's ok. And also I have `remove` function. It is going to like node, getting this like and `feedbackId` from this like. And then I make multi-part update.

```
static func remove(with userId: String, _ post: PostItem) {
  var updates: [String: Any?] = [
     "/userslikes/" + userId   + "/onposts/" + post.key: nil,
     "/postslikes/" + post.key + "/"         + userId:   nil
  ]

  // deleting from feedback node
  getLikeFromUser(id: userId, postId: post.key) { like in
     if like.userId != like.postAddedByUserId {
        updates.updateValue(nil, forKey: "/feedback/" + like.postAddedByUserId + "/" + like.key)
     }

     ref.updateChildValues(updates)
  }
}

static func getLikeFromUser(id: String, postId: String,
                           completion: @escaping (_ likeId: LikeItem) -> Void) {
  let refToLike = ref.child("/userslikes/" + id + "/onposts/" + postId)

  refToLike.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
     let like = LikeItem(snapshot: snapshot)

     completion(like)
  })
}
```

So, when user taps "remove like" I have some delay (It is fetching like entity to get feedback id at this time).

And the **problem**: If I'm spamming `like-removeLike` button (like - remove like - l - rl - l - rl etc.), sometimes my feedback node is duplicating (with different keys ofc. It has not removed old node) and sometimes it is not adding (in this situation it is crashing if I try to remove it in the future).

How to fix it?

Comment: My humble opinion, first of all this could be fix with UX limitations. User shouldn't be able to spam any button in application. Must be a delay between this events. Even you can add some max. switch between user decisions... wait a while and make it free again (maybe). If I understand correctly.

Comment: @gyer So, If I will block button, till previous data will be written to database, is it ok solution? You can also write answer. I can accept it, if no more answers will be given. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My humble opinion, first of all this could be fix with UX limitations. User shouldn't be able to spam any button in application. Must be a delay between this events. Even you can add some max. switch between user decisions... wait a while and make it free again (maybe).

Like you said on your comment, it's very good idea and good UX wait user until finish write operation. This way you can eliminate bad UX.

You can use [userinteractionenabled](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622577-userinteractionenabled) property of UIView.

> When set to NO, touch, press, keyboard, and focus events
>   intended for the view are ignored and removed from the event queue.
>   When set to YES, events are delivered to the view normally. The
>   default value of this property is YES.
>
> During an animation, user
>   interactions are temporarily disabled for all views involved in the
>   animation, regardless of the value in this property. You can disable
>   this behavior by specifying the 
>   UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction  option when configuring the
>   animation.

Of course there are many alternatives, sky is the limit for UX scenario.

Also you can check Apple's user interface guidelines for loading:

https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/interaction/loading/

> Show content as soon as possible. Don’t make people wait for content
>   to load before seeing the screen they're expecting. Show the screen
>   immediately, and use placeholder text, graphics, or animations to
>   identify where content isn't available yet. Replace these placeholder
>   elements as the content loads. Whenever possible, preload upcoming
>   content in the background, such as while an animation is playing or
>   the user is navigating a level or menu.

and indicators maybe:

https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-controls/progress-indicators/

> If it’s helpful, provide useful information while waiting for a task
>   to complete. Include a label above an activity indicator to give extra
>   context. Avoid vague terms like loading or authenticating because they
>   don’t usually add any value.

#### Another option

Like you said in your comment below there is another option to keep like/dislike until user lives the ViewController. But there is another UX problem that when user try to close modal or back to previous view controller they will wait until this background job finish. Another issue if user kills the application you have 1 change left to save data and it's AppDelegate's applicationWillTerminate. But it's bad practice to save data there because 5 seconds limit:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate

> This method lets your app know that it is about to be terminated and
>   purged from memory entirely. You should use this method to perform any
>   final clean-up tasks for your app, such as freeing shared resources,
>   saving user data, and invalidating timers. Your implementation of this
>   method has approximately **five seconds to perform any tasks and return**.
>
> **If the method does not return before time expires, the system may kill
>   the process altogether**. For apps that do not support background
>   execution or are linked against iOS 3.x or earlier, this method is
>   always called when the user quits the app. For apps that support
>   background execution, this method is generally not called when the
>   user quits the app because the app simply moves to the background in
>   that case. However, this method may be called in situations where the
>   app is running in the background (not suspended) and the system needs
>   to terminate it for some reason. After calling this method, the app
>   also posts a  UIApplicationWillTerminate  notification to give
>   interested objects a chance to respond to the transition.

Hope it helps.

Comment: only one thing is confusing me. Instagram doesn't block like button. Another option, that I has invented, is to save final state and update it only on leave from post info (cell or controller nvm). But idk what to do on closing the app, when user was on this page

Comment: You're right about Instagram. but they don't have any performance issues probably. It's not good idea to save changes on appdelegate applicationwillterminate, because you have 5 seconds limitation.

Comment: Maybe another approach. Start writing to db, when finished - check state of like, if it is another, than wrote, send another write request. Is it good?

Comment: Why? Look. 1) I tapped like - sending request - l - rl - l - rl - l - rl - completion of write operation - check state - changed - send another request. 2) I tapped like - sending request - l - rl - l - rl - l - completion of write operation - check state - did not change - dont send any request.

Comment: Ok. I'll make it. Also I'll wait till evening and accept if no other more good answer. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Thank you, good topics to talk about it :) Hope you'll make it great.

Comment: Me too:) Have a nice day

Comment: Well my last case is wrong. Idk actually why. I will lock interface. Thanks